# Scoped regions with child unity containers

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism, unity-container

I am using Prism for WPF with Unity - our application creates multiple child views (when a user "opens" an item) which in turn contain other regions whose views are created using view discovery, i.e.

```
// The various views used in the child are registered using 
// RegisterViewWithRegion in the module that implements that view
public void Initialize()
{
    regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ItemNavigation", typeof(ItemNavigationView));
    regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ItemContent", typeof(ItemContentView));
}
```

As we have multiple such child views being created each one must be created with its own scoped region manager (we decided against using multiple shells as it seemed over-complicated), however we also wish for each child view to have its own [child unity container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660895%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) so that we can inject item-specific dependencies.

This is how we create child views

```
var childContainer = container.CreateChildContainer();
childContainer.RegisterInstance(...);

var childView = childContainer.Resolve<ChildItemView>();
region.Add(childView, viewName, createRegionManagerScope: true);
```

Although the child unity container is used to correctly resolves dependencies for `ChildItemView`, when the nested views are created (`ItemNavigationView` and `ItemContentView`) the parent container is used instead and so some dependencies fail to resolve.

How can I associate my child unity container with the scoped region so that the correct unity container is used when resolving dependencies for the views created within that region?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have a similar situation.

Comment: @SimonGillbee I don't think I did. In hindsight having a bit more experience with dependency injection I have doubts about whether it is a good idea to use dependency injection in this way.

Comment: I've debated whether this is a good ideas or not. In my case I have a shell app with multiple independent modules and I would like each module to be isolated in its own container to make unloading and reloading easier.